# exclude routes in @metinseylan/nestjs-opentelemetry

Tags: node.js, nestjs, open-telemetry

I`m using @metinseylan/nestjs-opentelemetry
this way

```
import { OpenTelemetryModule } from '@metinseylan/nestjs-opentelemetry';
import { ZipkinExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-zipkin';
import { SimpleSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base';

@Module({
  imports: [
    OpenTelemetryModule.forRoot({
      spanProcessor: new SimpleSpanProcessor(
        new ZipkinExporter({
          url: 'your-zipkin-url',
        })
      ),
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How can i exclude routes for cubernetes probes like GET /live
from collecting traces?